# uitextfiled setSecureTextEntry is not working in ios6

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a textfiled of secure type i.e password textfield and I have one button when I am clicking on it is showing entered password.

Here is reference code...

```
 ......

UIButton *showPwdBtn = (UIButton*)sender;
showPwdBtn.selected = !showPwdBtn.selected;
[self.passwordTextField setSecureTextEntry:!showPwdBtn.selected];
.......
```

But when I am doing monkey testing after clicking randomly on show password button, setSecureTextentry is not updating uitextfiled with secure type.

When user will click on Show password password will be visible and when he deselect show password button password will again change to secure (*) text.

but unfortunate its not working for monkey testing...why setSecureTextentry is not updating?

Comment: Did you check that `self.passwordTextField` contains the text field you expect?

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this

```
showPwdBtn.selected = !showPwdBtn.selected;
[self.passwordTextField setSecureTextEntry:showPwdBtn.selected];
```

with only one not operation

Comment: The code looks good to me. The first line is to toggle the boolean, the second ! is to convert from "show" to "hide" semantics.

Comment: I edited the code and I have checked it showing YES and NO for every clicks but after clicking random it is setting with YES.